# How do I know final OnDraw is called?

Tags: mfc

`OnDraw` is called two or three times when program starts.

I want to display dialog box automatically after final OnDraw is called.
The dialog box size depends on the size of view.

How can I do that?

```
void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    DrawSomething(pDC);
    m_wndDlg.Create(IDD_DLG1, this); // I want to create the dialog box only once
}
```

Comment: Why is the size only known after the `WM_PAINT` handler runs?

Comment: Because I want dialog box is created only once. Anyway where is the best place to create dialog box after all paint is done?

Comment: Why is it important that the dialog is displayed only after a certain number of calls to the `WM_PAINT` handler have run? Why does that matter? What's special about your program that prevents a modal dialog from dispatching any pending `WM_PAINT` messages?

Comment: I edited question. I don't want to create dialog box two or three times.

Comment: If you want to create a dialog only once, then create the dialog only once. You could do this by taking note after you've created it the first time around, and not attempt to create it again. Or you could move the code to a place that's executed exactly once due to the nature of how the system (and framework) works, such as the [`CView::OnInitialUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cview-class#oninitialupdate) implementation. It's certainly unusual to do anything but render the contents of a view in a `WM_PAINT` handler.

Comment: CView::OnInitialUpdate is called before OnDraw. Size of view is not known when OnInitialUpdate is called.

Comment: Why do you assume that the size weren't known? **Of course** it is known at that time. You've probably stuffed everything you didn't know where else to put into your `WM_PAINT` handler, such as dialog creating, sizing, and so on. It's probably a good idea to drop MFC and [learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) how to write a Windows program without using a framework you have no chance of ever understanding without a solid foundation.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is pretty simple: do NOT create your dialog in `OnDraw`

Comment: I know OnDraw is not proper place. But , dialog box depends on view size, I can not create dialog box in OnIniialUpdate. After final size of view is known, dialog box must be created.

Comment: @0627235 Try creating a handler for WM_SHOWWINDOW message and create your dialog from there. Even then, you should set up some kind of a flag to tell you if that dialog was already created.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the literal question first: There's no way to know, whether any given [`WM_PAINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/wm-paint) message is the final `WM_PAINT` message. The system cannot possibly predict future user actions. Often times the user doesn't even know, either!

The earliest time when you can be confident that there will be no future `WM_PAINT` messages is when handling the [`WM_NCDESTROY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-ncdestroy) message, the final message sent to a window before it has been fully destroyed.

Clearly, trying to solve a problem based on a condition that cannot be decided until after it is too late isn't going to be successful. You're going to have to find a different solution.

The clunkiest of solutions is to manually record whether you have displayed the dialog already, and not show it again if you have. You *could* change your `OnDraw()` implementation to something like this:

```cpp
void CMyView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{
    DrawSomething(pDC);

    // Manually store state
    static bool is_dialog_created{ false };
    if (!is_dialog_created) {
        m_wndDlg.Create(IDD_DLG1, this);
        is_dialog_created = true;
    }

    // Or

    // Reuse state you already have
    if (m_wndDlg.m_hWnd == nullptr) {
        m_wndDlg.Create(IDD_DLG1, this);
    }
}
```

Not something that anyone should do, really. `OnDraw()` has a single purpose: Displaying a visual representation of the document associated with the view. It should not have any other side effects.

If you need to dynamically create controls or dialogs, that should be done in a callback that's designed for this purposed. [`CWnd::OnCreate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#oncreate) is the most common place to dynamically create controls. It's argument provides information on the requested size, in case that is important.

If for some reason you have to delay that creation further until other aspects of the UI have settled to a state where the UI is about to be displayed, the `CView` class provides the [`CView::OnInitialUpdate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cview-class#oninitialupdate) method you can implement. You'll want to call the base class implementation first, and when that returns everything is properly sized/position (but not yet displayed).

Comment: I tried them already. Flag does not work because flag is set when OnDraw is called first time, not last time. In my program, OnInitialUpdate is called before final OnDraw. So, it does not work. I created dialog box at the end of CMyApp::InitInstance(). It works fine. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Even after seeing a proof of why what you're asking for **cannot** exist, you're coming back, asking for it all over again. I suppose you're just immune to logical reasoning. Let's leave it at that. Wishing you a fine career in a field where reason is purely optional.

Answer (score 0):

`OnDraw` is not the good place.
If you want to display your dialog once and only once, use `DoDataExchange` as follows:

```
void CStackOverFlowDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    if ( !pDX->m_bSaveAndValidate )
    {
        // This part will be called once (and only once) when loading the window.
        // All your Dialog controls are already created at this stat
        // ADD your dialogbox here ...
    }

    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}
```